# Sprintf, fetch, from Prepared Statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

This code doesn't work. I was trying to change from the traditional mysqli queries to prepared statements, but actually don't happen anything with this.

Some help?

```
<?php
include_once("config.inc.php"); // DataBase connection.
$collection = '100';
$results = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT p.ID, p.Reference, p.Collection, p.Name, i.ImageOne FROM p INNER JOIN i ON p.Reference=i.Reference WHERE p.Collection=?");
if ($results === FALSE) {
  trigger_error($mysqli_conn->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$results->bind_param("s", $collection);
$results->bind_result($ID, $Reference, $Collection, $Name, $ImageOne);  
$results->execute();
echo '<div class="scroll-pane">';
while ($results->fetch()) {
$body = '
<div class="product">
    <a href="/product.php?id=%s">
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="txt">%s</p>
            </div>
            <div style="height:8em;margin:0 auto;">
                <img src="%s" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
';
sprintf($body, $ID, $Name, $ImageOne);
}
echo '</div>';
$results->free_result();
$results->close();
```

Comment: what error are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the execute and bind_result statements.

```
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($ID, $Reference, $Collection, $Name, $ImageOne);
```

Before `$results->execute();` is called, there are no results to bind to the variables.

[mysqli_stmt::bind_results() Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)